# Cannot import moment.js using ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

Then inside `script.js`:

```
import { moment as mymoment } from "./moment.js";
var a = mymoment('2016-01-01');
```

But it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: moment
```

I can see it downloading the `moment.js` file in the developer console (F12). I think it finds the file but then inside the file it cannot find a `moment` module.

There is a documentation at [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/) about how to import moment.js. So it definitely supports `import`. But the title of the documentation says "Node.js". I don't know why because `import` is pure JS and I don't want to use Node.js. I want to import it using pure JavaScript.

I am using Firefox 102.8.0esr (64-Bit) and moment.js 2.29.4. The moment.js file can be found [here](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js).

Update:
I have a web chart which requires a recent moment.js. This web chart can be embedded into foreign web sites. Because the foreign web site could already be using a very old moment.js version I need an alias.

The normal moment.js (that is when you download the normal version from momentjs.com) does not support modules. I didn't know that moment.js is deprecated for ever (there is an official statement [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)). And this might be the reason why it doesn't support modules. I will switch to day.js which supports modules by default.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/

Comment: @KooiInc I need to use import because I need to have an alias.

Comment: Looks like *moment.js* is not an ES6 module. The browser build of momentjs will just expose a global `moment` variable, don't use that one. Not sure if they distribute a module, if not, you might have to build it yourself.

Comment: According to [the ES6 syntax documentation](//momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/) it’s a _default_ export, not a named export. So you need `import mymoment from "./moment.js"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Then it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default".

Comment: @Bergi Then why is there an official documentation where moment.js is imported using the `import` keyword?

Comment: @zomega If both kinds of import fail, then the script you found does not export anything. You found the wrong script. Find the ECMAScript module version of moment.js.

Comment: @zomega You read the documentation for node.js or for TypeScript, not the documentation on how to use it with a `<script>` in the browser?

Comment: @Bergi The import statement is pure JavaScript. It doesn't require Node.js. I cannot use the script tag because I need an alias.

Comment: Sure - you just need to import the right file. All I'm saying is that "*it definitely supports import*" is not a given when "*the title of the documentation says "Node.js"*". It does work here (see @TachibanaShin's answer), since moment.js is a library that does not have further dependencies and does not require native node modules, but your conclusion is not valid in general.

Answer (score 4):

you have to find the correct version of `esm` and use cdn (unpkg, esm.sh...) or download:

```js
import moment from "https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/dist/moment.js"

console.log(moment)
```

Comment: you can download or do something with this file but i prefer to use cdn like skypack.dev

Comment: This works. But what is esm? Can I get this file from momentjs directly?

Comment: @zomega “esm” stands for ECMAScript module. That’s what you need.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I want to get this file directly from momentjs. How to build it or where to find it?

Comment: @zomega all cdn approach moment.js is taken directly from moment.js you don't need to worry about it you can refer https://npmjs.org/package/moment and you will see these files

Comment: "*you have to find the correct version of esm*" - how to do that? Is it documented in the moment.js docs somewhere?

Comment: @Bergi this is general knowledge I don't think package developers (myself included) like to write things over and over again

Comment: @TachibanaShin So it's unpkg.com and esm.sh that provide these builds, not the moment.js maintainers? How do they build and bundle them without a configuration?

Comment: @Bergi unpkg.com provides the package from moment.js directly with no processing and skypack.dev and esm.sh they use a translator of different formats to esm code (skypack v1 which was later integrated into vite )

Comment: Ah I see moment.js do provide `"jsnext:main": "./dist/moment.js"` as an entrypoint in their *package.json*. Which kinda makes sense since they support nodejs. One just needs to use https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/dist/moment.js instead of https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/moment.js… And of course it's not necessary to use that from a CDN, one could (should) just install that package oneself and serve the module on one's page.

Answer (score 1):

The *browser version* of `moment.js` is not a module. If you need an alias, you can create your own variable `mymoment`. Something like:

```js
const mymoment = moment;
let a = mymoment('2016-01-01'); 
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Aside: `moment.js` is deprecated and now has [legacy state](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Maybe my [es-date-fiddler module](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler) is useful.

Comment: "*The browser version of moment.js is not a module.*" - true, however one can use the non-browser version which is an ES6 module, it still works in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bundling your JS scripts you may have to import momentjs as an external script, better from a CDN ([cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js) or [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/moment))

You would have this in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-CryKbMe7sjSCDPl18jtJI5DR5jtkUWxPXWaLCst6QjH8wxDexfRJic2WRmRXmstr2Y8SxDDWuBO6CQC6IE4KTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<scrip src="script.js"></script>
```

And remove the import statement from your script.js

see:

- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/

---

Update after your comment:

What you are trying to achieve might not be possible unless you are using a module bundler (like [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)) that bundles momentjs to your script.

The CDN approach might not be the best as multiple MomentJS versions [may conflict](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3298#issuecomment-231880594) between them.

What you can do is check if momentjs is already present on the page before you inject the script that loads it for you (this will hurt your library's performance), if it's present you create a temporary variable and save the previous reference for `moment` and then switch the two variables. That's not the cleanest approach, and you don't want to go for, I believe.

One other unrelated comment, if you not using any other libraries that requires `momentjs` precisely, consider using the DOM's native [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), or go for a lighter library like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) as [MomentJS is now being depricated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/)

Comment: But I need an alias.

Comment: Why? There must be a workaround to achieve what you want without alias. Or are you using some sort of a bundler like rollup or webpack?

Comment: I offer a chart which can be included into foreign websites. It depends on a recent moment.js (not too old). Now when somebody includes my chart it's possible this site uses a very old moment.js version and the moment global object is already set. This is why I need an alias.

Comment: Updated my answer, TLDR; you may need a module bundler like and then just bundle your script with the right library version for you, also, you may want to look for other alternatives to momentjs

Comment: why do you think we need a rollup for a trivial problem like this `import` syntax is available in es6 and has been promoted for standardization by Evan You (vue author)